# How to fix issue in Python program printing hollow squares

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to make a program where hollow squares are made based on the user input. The code is running correctly except for one part. Can anyone suggest a way to fix this?
My code looks like this:

```
    size = int(input("Please enter size of square "))
    for row in range(size-1):
        print("*",end=" ")
    for column in range(size-1):
        print("*",end=" ")
        for i in range(size-2):
            print(" ",end=" ")
        print("*")
    for row in range(size):
        print("*",end=" ")
```

I want the code to print out like this:

For example: size = 4

```
     ****
     *  *
     *  *
     ****
```

But when I run the code the square comes out as this:

For example: size = 4

```
      ****    *
      *  *
      *  *
      ****
```

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a print("") after the first loop. Right now it's printing the first and second row on the same line.

```
size = int(input("Please enter size of square "))
for row in range(size):
    print("*",end=" ")
print("") # add this to change the row
for column in range(size-1):
    print("*",end=" ")
    for i in range(size-2):
        print(" ",end=" ")
    print("*")
for row in range(size):
    print("*",end=" ")
```

Comment: It will miss the last `*` of the first line, the printing after the for-loop should be of a `"*"` not of `""`

Comment: Ah, yeah, I copied the code and just added that one line.

Answer (score 0):

Add another print right after the first for loop:

```
for row in range(size-1):
    print("*",end=" ")
print("*")  # <-- add this line
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Column range size needs to be reduced by 2, in addition to the above changes mentioned.

```
for i in range(size):
    print ("*", end=" ")
print(" ") # <-- added this line

for column in range(size-2): # <-- modified this line
    print("*",end=" ")
    for i in range(size-2):
        print(" ",end=" ")
    print("*")

for i in range(size):
    print ("*", end=" ")
```